# Заменить значение параметра url

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Как заменить параметр url c https://site.ru/index.php?ht=1032 на https://site.ru/index.php?ht=116 при условии, что параметров может быть больше и они все должны сохраниться?
Пример:
https://site.ru/index.php?x=10&ht=1032&y=20
должен измениться на 
https://site.ru/index.php?x=10&ht=116&y=20

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, может кому пригодится

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?ht=1032(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://site.ru/index.php?%1ht=116%2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Для `nginx`

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*&)?ht=1032(&.*)?$){return 301 $uri?$1ht=116$2;}
```